# UIView with adaptable height according to content - Objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk

I would like to create an UIView that fits his content. The content is an UILabel with dinamic text.

```
UIView *myview = [ [UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 700.0, 100.0)];
myview.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:myview];

UILabel *myLabel = [ [UILabel alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 500.0, 43.0) ];
myLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" size:(36.0)];
[myView addSubview:myLabel];
myLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
myLabel.text = @"This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. ";
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```

I attach a screenshot:

[Screenshot](http://i52.tinypic.com/bg36oj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this after `[myLabel sizeToFit]`:

```
[myView setFrame:myLabel.frame];
```

Comment: Almost!! This is okay, but it doesn't maintain the margin. Look: http://i54.tinypic.com/15gpmy8.png

Comment: And I think that this will not be the solution, cause I will need to put another label below this.

Comment: You just need to add the frames of the two labels, but I guess you've figured that out already. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
NSString *tempString = @"This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. This is an UILabel. ";

    CGSize constSize = { 260.0f, 20000.0f };

CGSize textSizeTitle = [tempString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0] constrainedToSize:constSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

UILabel *EventTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 260,textSizeTitle.height)];
[EventTitle setText:tempString];
[EventTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[EventTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TrebuchetMS-Bold" size:20]];
[EventTitle setNumberOfLines:0];
[EventTitle setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[EventTitle setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[newsBox addSubview:EventTitle];
```

Just ensure, font size of textSizeTitle & EventTitle should be same.